# How to remove the following Apple Mach-O-Linker Error with AssestsLibrary in iOS?

Tags: ios, linker-errors, xcode6.1

```
Ld /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Radius-cxycjazfyueurigdymnvyxtqwulq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Radius.app/Radius normal x86_64
    cd /Users/Admin/Desktop/Radius/Radius
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Radius-cxycjazfyueurigdymnvyxtqwulq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/Admin/Desktop/Radius/Radius/Radius -F/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Radius-cxycjazfyueurigdymnvyxtqwulq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Admin/Desktop/Radius/Radius/Radius -filelist /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Radius-cxycjazfyueurigdymnvyxtqwulq/Build/Intermediates/Radius.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Radius.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Radius.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -framework FacebookSDK -framework AssetsLibrary -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Radius-cxycjazfyueurigdymnvyxtqwulq/Build/Intermediates/Radius.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Radius.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Radius_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Radius-cxycjazfyueurigdymnvyxtqwulq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Radius.app/Radius

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Admin/Desktop/Radius/Radius/Radius/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Admin/Desktop/Radius/Radius/Radius/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EditProfileViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Where did `/Users/Admin/Desktop/Radius/Radius/Radius/AssetsLibrary.framework` come from?

Comment: Its an external library. I added it.

Comment: Well it clearly does not contain the `x86_64` architecture.  You will need to obtain a version that does contain that architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the library and its references. Cleaned the project, again added the required libraries and checked all references and linking, Build and run the project.

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

The "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1" usually occurs when you accidentally added(import) the implementation file(.m) in place of the header(.h) file.

Check and confirm if EditProfileViewController.m is not imported.

Comment: That's true if the error is reporting **duplicate** symbols, not so much for undefined ones.

Comment: I checked. No imports are there for implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that /Users/Admin/Desktop/Radius/Radius/Radius/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary is missing an x86_64 simulator slice.

Assuming you built that framework yourself, update it with i386 and x86_64 simulator slices (build for i386 and x86_64 and then lipo the resulting slices into the universal framework).

If you got it from a 3rd party, contact them for a version of the framework that has all the appropriate slices.

Comment: I used the same framework in another app. Its working fine there but when I dragged and dropped in this project, the linker error popped up.

Comment: Well the other project either didn't use rhe ALAssetsLibrary class or was not built for x86_64